# Как переписать импорт пакета под es6?

Tags: node.js

Помогите переписать импорт на ES6
Вот мой импорт

```
const mailchimpClient = require("mailchimp_transactional")("YOUR_API_KEY");
```

Нужно переписать на

```
import {} from 'mailchimp_transactional'
```

Comment: Если ответ @the-solomon был вам полезен, отметьте его как правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, то вот так:

```
import mailchimpClient from "mailchimp_transactional"

const chimp = mailchimpClient("YOU_API_KEY");
```